# React native NavigationExperimental and MapView gestures

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native

I am using [react native maps](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps) to load Map inside a screen that contains NavigationHeader. I am using NavigationExperimental and my navigation code is below.

The problem is that I can't move through map or anything, it doesn't pick up any events. MapView works in a container that doesn't contain the NavigationHeader and that's why I think those two connected is the issue.

React Native version is 0.28, testing on Android only.

**App.js**

```
render() {
 return (
  <NavigationTransitioner
    navigationState={navigationState}
    style={styles.outerContainer}
    onNavigate={onNavigate}
    renderOverlay={props => {
      const title = props.scene.route.title;
      return (title !== '' ?
        <NavigationHeader
          {...props}
          renderTitleComponent={() => (
            <NavigationHeader.Title>
              {title}
            </NavigationHeader.Title>
          )}
        />
      : null);
    }}
    renderScene={props => (
      <NavigationCard
        {...props}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        key={props.scene.route.key}
      />
            )}
  />
    );
 }
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
render() {
return (

  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch' }}
    <MapView
      {...this.props}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 45.79,
        longitude: 16,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421 }}
    />
  </View>
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets directly. What have you tried already?

Comment: @AnimiVulpis sorry, I did now. I tried using onStartShouldSetResponderCapture and onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture on MyComponent's View and App's NavigationHeader in many ways but always the same...

Answer (score 0):

Working with RN 0.29.2 and rn-maps 0.7.1.